# When one uses "povu" instead of "devas", what is the nuance?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

`Povu` probably means "should", according to the Esperanto Bible: 
https://bit.ly/2FMTKVo

However, we already have `devi`. So I wonder, is there any nuance being expressed here?

I looked up PIV, Wikipedia, and ReVo, with no meaningful results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot read the text when I follow the link; is it Job 9:32?

> *Ĉar Li ne estas homo simile al mi,
>   
> Ke mi **povu** respondi al Li,
>   
> Ke ni **povu** ambaŭ iri al juĝo.*
>
> For he is not a man, as I am,
> that I **should** answer him,
> and we **should** come together in judgment. (KJV)

Here are more modern translations:

> If God were human, I **could** answer him; we **could** go to court to decide our quarrel. (GNT)
>
> He is not a mere mortal like me that I **might** answer him, that we **might** confront each other in court. (NIV)

The KJV's use of *should* here, to mean merely *would*,  is not totally archaic, but it is old-fashioned. Here is a quotation from *Alice in Wonderland*:

> "For it might end, you know, [...] in my going out altogether, like a candle. I wonder what I **should** be like then?"

She isn't talking about what she *ought* to be, but about what she *would* be. It was formerly laid down as a rule in English that *would* cannot be used after *I* or *we*; it had to be replaced by *should*, and that *I will* implies a desire. This idea originated in the distinctions made by scholars translating from Latin:

> The rule is [...] to express a future event without emotional overtones, one should say I shall, we shall, but you/he/she/they will; conversely, for emphasis, willfulness, or insistence, one should say I/we will, but you/he/she/they shall.
>
> —John Wallis, *Grammatica Linguae Anglicanae* (1653)

Thus in the quotation from the Book of Job, *ke mi povu respondi* means "so that I would be able to answer", and the use of *povu* instead of just *povus* implies that it is a desire: Job *would like* to make an answer.